# Storing private keys in database

Tags: security, encryption, key, private

I have the need to store private keys for multiple users, so that my server application can sign files on their behalf.

I want to store the private keys securely, but I couldn't find best practices around this. If I was storing a password I would salt+hash the password to make a hash that can't be easily turned back into the password. However, with a private key I need to store it in a way I can later retrieve it.

I was thinking I would encrypt the private key and then store it in my database. I originally thought each key would be encrypted with a different password (based on some properties of the user). However, those properties would most likely be stored in the database, so if my database got leaked then the attacker has everything.

I could encrypt all private keys with a single password that is only known to my application. Then an attacker would have to steal my database, and my application to do any harm.

Is there a technique/best practice I'm missing?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could encrypt the private key with a symmetric key based on the users password. Simply store an additional salt and perform the password "hash" to get a separate key. Then use that as key for encrypting the private key. Note that it is required to use a Password Based **Key** Derivation Function (PBKDF) such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt to create a secure password hash (given the normal security level of a password).

If the user is not online at the time that a signature needs to be generated, then you should indeed protect the passwords in a sense that only you / our backoffice can decrypt the keys. You can use some user ID + your own secret key to calculate an encryption/decryption key. You may even want to generate a separate RSA key pair to perform hybrid encryption decryption.

Storing private keys on behalf of users is a very dangerous practice. There are a lot of ways for the private key to become exposed (e.g. side channel attacks). To do it professionally you should really be using an HSM somewhere in the process. If this is for any serious data, please consult a professional and a lawyer.

Comment: Hey Maarten, could you explain where "Simply store an additional salt" comes into play in this process?

Comment: @wimdetr PBKDF2 requires a unique salt per key derivation, and in this case the symmetric key should be generated with a different password / salt combination. The resulting symmetric key (and, usually IV) can then be used to wrap (encrypt) the private key. It doesn't matter where the salt is stored as long as it can be retrieved for the wrapped key for decryption. Maybe read PKCS#5 (password based encryption) for more info.